# how to gather the code of a designed banner

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a simple form which designs a banner for user website it have color schemes, links and link colors a horizontal banner or vertical banner etc user selects his desired banner by selecting values from drop down boxes and submits that data is stored in a mysql database 
now what i want is that collect that data and send it to the user basically to display the banner on his website now how to make that HTML pack of code i know how to send it by email from PHP but the matter is how will be that pack of html code made and then send to him

any article will be helpfull

Comment: Provide code and a specific question please

Answer (score 0):

You could use some HTML template for banner. It will change depending on values set by user.